# Function will not execute more then once

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a hangman game with an on-screen keyboard, there is alot more code then this but this is the specfic function that won't run.  The HTML is just an example of one key, there are 27 including a space, all of them only run the wrong() function once.
Here's the HTML that executes the function:

```
<p class="key" id="q" onclick="q(); setTimeout(allclick, 200); setTimeout(wrong, 1000);" onmouseover="hoverq()" onmouseout="unhoverq()">Q</p>
```

And the script that should fire off everytime one of the keys is pressed but it doesn't.

```
<script>
function wrong(){
        console.log("wrong()")
        console.log(clickon)
        if(wrong == length){
          console.log("all wrong")
          document.getElementById(clickon).setAttribute("onmouseover", " ")
          document.getElementById(clickon).setAttribute("onmouseout", " ")
          document.getElementById(clickon).setAttribute("onclick", " ")
          document.getElementById(clickon).style.backgroundColor="red"
        }else{
          wrongcheck = 1
          console.log(wrongcheck)
        }
        console.log("_____")
</script>
```

Edit:
This may help you understand this better.

```
var length = word.length;

function allclick(){
      for(l = 0; l <= length; l++){
        if(clickon == letter[l]){
          if(clickon == " "){
            document.getElementById("blank" + l).innerHTML = " "
            document.getElementById("space").setAttribute("onmouseover", "")
            document.getElementById("space").setAttribute("onmouseout", "")
            document.getElementById("space").setAttribute("onclick", "")
            document.getElementById("space").style.backgroundColor="green"
            document.getElementById("blank" + l).style.margin = "5px 50px"
          }else{
          console.log("correct")
            document.getElementById("blank" + l).innerHTML = clickon + "&nbsp"
            document.getElementById(clickon).setAttribute("onmouseover", "")
            document.getElementById(clickon).setAttribute("onmouseout", "")
            document.getElementById(clickon).setAttribute("onclick", "")
            document.getElementById(clickon).style.backgroundColor="green"
          }
          }else if(clickon != letter[l]){
            wrong = wrongcheck++
        }
        }
        console.log("_____")
      }
```

if you want I can send you the entire thing.

Comment: What's `clickon`? It's not `q` is it?

Comment: What is `if(wrong == length)` supposed to do?

Comment: @Carcigenicate clickon is equal to the vaule that you select, if you select q clickon will be q and compare it to the answer.

Comment: Nightmare putting all those timeouts in html `onclick`. Combine all that logic on one event handler function by calling other functions from within it. Even better is learn how to use `addEventListener` and separate concerns...html in one place, javascript in another. This is the more modern approach

Comment: Why are you using setTimeout? Also onclick expects a single function, I kind of am surprised it works even once

Comment: Is your wrong function not closed or you missed when pasting here? https://jsfiddle.net/ny1rtd2o/